# Can the diode be ignored in this Op amp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, diodes

> Consider the circuit below:
>
> [image]
>
> The diode is ideal and \$R=1000\Omega\$.
>
> What is \$v_o\$ when \$v_{in}=3V\$?
>
> What is \$v_o\$ when \$v_{in}=-3V\$?

So my idea was just to make node equations to solve these to find \$v_o\$, but when I do that I completely ignore the diode. I do like this.

For this op amp we have: \$v_-=v_+=0V\$

**When \$v_{in}=3V\$:**

\$\frac{v_--3V}{R}+\frac{v_--v_o}{R}=0\$

Inserting \$v_-=0V\$ and solving this equation we find that: \$v_o=-3V\$

**When \$v_{in}=-3V\$:**

\$\frac{v_-+3V}{R}+\frac{v_--v_o}{R}=0\$

Inserting \$v_-=0V\$ and solving this equation we find that: \$v_o=3V\$

As you can see, I'm not really thinking about the diode at all. Am I solving the problem correctly?

Comment: How does V- stay at 0V when Vo is at -3V and there's a forward-biased diode between them?

Comment: You can't ignore the diode if Vin is in a direction that turns it on and shorts out the feedback resistor.

Comment: Ahh you are right, I didn't think about the diode shorting the circuit.

Comment: Phil G, doesn't an Op Amp force the voltage on both inputs to be the same?

Comment: @Carl Its the other way around , if the Vcm input is in a valid range, the input error is what forces the output how to eliminate the null. So if R1=10k and Vin=3V then 0.3mA then Vout = -0.5 approx and 0V in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLWQ2Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- When Vi > 0 the diode conducts and shorts out R2. Stability will be reached when Vo = -0.7 V (for a real Si diode) and at 0 V for the ideal diode in the question.
- When Vi < 0 the diode is reverse biased and is effectively out of the circuit. \$ V_O = - V_I \$.
- The circuit when created with a real diode is an imperfect (due to the -0.7 V output) inverting half-wave rectifier.

---

From the comments:

> Doesn't an op-amp force the voltage on both inputs to be the same?

Yes, in negative feedback configuration.

- In Figure 1b we have a current flowing through R3 tending to raise the voltage on the inverting input. This will cause the output to swing negative.
- When the output swings to just below zero (or just below -0.7 V with a real diode) the input will have been pulled down to 0 V and will match the voltage at the non-inverting input. The output will stabilise at that point.

Comment: But since the diode is ideal, what does that do to your result. Does that mean that stability occurs at Vo = 0 V instead of Vo = -0.7V?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the ideal diode in the question. Yes, Vo = 0 V. I'll fix the answer. Thank you for accepting my answer.

Comment: No. Thank YOU for helping me out!